# MongoDB authentication failed after enabling user access control

Tags: mongodb

I'm using latest MongoDB in windows Server 2016 standard, trying to setup Authentication. here was my step to follow.

```
# mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
# mongo --port 27017
# use admin



     db.createUser(
          {
            user: "myUserAdmin",
            pwd: "abc123",
            roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
          }
        )

# mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1

# use admin

# db.auth("myUserAdmin", "abc123" )

after all I got 

    C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo
    MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
    connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
    Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("63f22acf-9f5b-4949-b804-82d141ba2761") }
    MongoDB server version: 4.0.3
    > use admin
    switched to db admin
    > db.auth("myUserAdmin", "abc123" )
    Error: Authentication failed.
    0
    >
```

please help.. I'm very new

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/ ? Please also ensure that `db.version()` and `version()` shows the same number.

Comment: I think i have to create root user first.. but documentation did not mentioned that. i have created root and problem solved.. i hope..

Answer (score 0):

After create the user you need to restart mongod and mongo. Restart mongod with the following command

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
```

Now open command prompt and connect mongo with the following command

```
mongo --port 27017 -u user_name -p password --authenticationDatabase database_name
```

Now use the following command

```
use admin
db.auth("myUserAdmin", "abc123" )
```

May be it will help you.